# How to make the text field not null in a jsp page. I have googled it but could not find any relevant answer

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

How to make the text field not null in a jsp page. I have googled it but could not find any relevant answer

Comment: <p><label class="left-col">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username"value="" placeholder=""></p> 
this is my text field how to make it not null.

Comment: please describe make it null here . how do you want to do it , or do you want to make it disabled ?

Comment: actually i want my username text field to be not null . suppose some user enters a null vale then it should throw an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using html 5 ,

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" required/>
```

is enough.

yours as ,

```
<p><label class="left-col">Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" required/>   </p>
```

***NOTE***: It works on the modern browser only . you can go for the `javascript` validation .If you want it to work for older versions

Comment: i guess that won't be a problem

Comment: If it was helpful consider upvoting and accepting the answer else let me know if for issues :)

Comment: sorry i cant upvote coz its my first post but i have accepted the answer

Answer (score 0):

Use html 5. Using `required` attribute will make it not null in a jsp page.

```
<label for="email">Email : </label>
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" required />
<br/>
<br/>
<label for="password">Password : </label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" minlength="5" maxlength="10" required />
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"/>
```